# Calling javascript from objective-c code

Tags: javascript, objective-c, iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I found a lots of ways to call objective-c code from javascript, but I want to call the javascript code from objective-c. Last time I submitted a HTML FORM from objective-c, and now I wan't to call a javascript method. What do you think, is there any way to call it and get the response? I am interested in any solution, but I started to think and I think I need to send a html call or something like this, but I am not sure about this because the javascript is client side code, so maybe I need to process it from my objective-c code.
What do you think about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are using a WebKit embedded in your app to link JavaScript to your "native" Obj-C code right?

If so you simply do this:

```
    NSString* script = @"function __wrapper() { return (typeof webNodeEvent == \"function\") } __wrapper();";

    id resultObj = [nodeScriptObject evaluateWebScript:script];

    if ([resultObj boolValue]) { // its there, call it

        [nodeScriptObject callWebScriptMethod:@"webNodeEvent" withArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:eventType]];

    }
```

The nodeScriptObject is from the WebView and is just the JavaScript object.

Comment: That's very cool. I didn't imagine that it is as simple as you too said. Thanks a lot guys. I'll try each two methods then I will replay with answer here.

Comment: i don't understand where you have the script file etc. could you please elaborate the above code a bit more? thx a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for UIWebView's [stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: method](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:)?

This lets you run JS code inside of the sandbox of a web view, from Objective-C.

Comment: Look my comment at ExitToShell's answer. And thanks for you too. :)