# How do I call javaScript from Objective C?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, safari, webkit

I'm developing a WebKit Safari Plugin with Xcode. How do I call JavaScript from `-webPlugInStart`?

Comment: Maybe [this question and it's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463710/calling-javascript-from-objective-c-code) will help?

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't understand how do I use it in my method and run it on plugin launch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should remember the containing view:

```
+ (NSView *)plugInViewWithArguments:(NSDictionary *)arguments {
    return [[self alloc] initWithArguments:arguments];
}    

- (id)initWithArguments:(NSDictionary*)arguments {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        webView = [[[arguments objectForKey:WebPlugInContainerKey] webFrame] webView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

When you have that, you can refer to the documentation on ["Using JavaScript From Objective-C"](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/JavaScriptFromObjC.html). E.g.:

```
- (void)webPlugInStart {
    WebScriptObject *scriptObj = [webView windowScriptObject];
    NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
        @"someString", [NSNumber numberWithInt:42], nil];
    [scriptObj callWebScriptMethod:@"myJsFunction" withArguments:args];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It really is as simple as calling..

```
WebScriptObject *jsObj = [webView windowScriptObject];
NSString *script = @"$('That's a HUGE vageen.').text('#yourDiv');";
[scriptObject evaluateWebScript:script];
```

*Ta da!*  And don't let the weird dearth of people doing it - deter you from such *sexiness* as...

```
DOMDocument *myDOMDocument = [[webView mainFrame] DOMDocument];
DOMElement *paraBlock = [myDOMDocument getElementById:@"thatDiv"];
DOMElement *newPara = [myDOMDocument createElement:@"p"];
DOMText *newText = [myDOMDocument createTextNode:@"John Resig is a fool."];
[newPara appendChild:newText];
[paraBlock appendChild:newPara];
```

It's like jQuery!  *But it's Objective-C.* Oh Joy!