# Call Javascript function in background task in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, webview

I have a phonegap app and I want to execute Javascript code in a background task. When the application enters background I start executing a javascript function which takes data out of a web database and sends some values to a web service, the returning data may toggle a push-notification to the user.

I found either how to call javascript from Objective-C [here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463710/calling-javascript-from-objective-c-code) and how to implement Long-Running Background Tasks in the [iOS SDK Documentation pages](https://web.archive.org/web/20140824215114/https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html), but I haven't found anything in combining both (what I think is e.g.: When I invoke javascript code via a webview, does this View even exist when the App is in background?) so I want to ask some more experienced iOS Developers if this is even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its really possible. Javascript requires a UIwebview to run (in realtime) and must be visible to the user. When an app is put in background only a small amount of tasks are allowed to run- webview not one of them.

Your better off sending your data to a web server that runs a cron-job or similar to send out a push notification via apples push notification server - You can also bypass this and use a service like http://urbanairship.com/

Comment: I'm on exactly this way now. You confirmed what I assumed. I dont use urban airship though, because I read it´s reduced to 1 Mio Notifications a month for the free plan. I use the PushNotification Plugin on Github, Link: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/PushNotification. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I have also used this plugin.. Works well!

Answer (score 1):

I experimented with this on iOS 5+ and it's possible. I created a small PhoneGap plugin that demonstrates how this works. Check it out, and see the README for most of the info.

https://github.com/jocull/phonegap-backgroundjs